# CornerRadius in a uiview that uses ACEDrawingView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cornerradius

I'm currently using [ACEDrawingView](https://github.com/acerbetti/ACEDrawingView) and everything works awesome as far as the drawing and all of the functionally it suppose to bring but for some reason if I try to round the corners of the view using ACEDrawingView it doesn't work as expected. Let me rephrase this, I do see the radius applied but also a sharp corner underneath. See the attached image.

Any idea why cornerRadius doesn't work properly when applied to a uiview that uses ACEDrawingView?

This is how I'm applying the radii

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
```

FYI - The radius works fine if I change the class to be UIView instead of ACEDrawingView.

Thanks a lot[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting masksToBound = YES made the trick.

myView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

I could delete my question but I rather leave it here in case someone else runs into a similar issue.

One important point: I don't think ACEDrawingView was doing anything, this seems to happen to any view that is not using the default UIView class.